# Cannot save/run GAMS file to/from mapped SharePoint network drive

Tags: sharepoint, gams-math

I am trying to run a model in GAMS (using the Windows GAMS 64, version 24.5).  The model .gms file is located on a Z drive that is mapped to a SharePoint folder.  We use this setup all the time with other programming languages without problem.  But when I try to run or save my model, I get the following error:

```
Unable to save file:

Z:\[my file path]\mymodel.gms

Error 123: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

When I try to run the file, I also get the following message in the process window:

```
*** Error: Error writing GAMSNext: Invalid argument
Exit code = 113
```

SharePoint is really useful in tracking versions and letting the teams collaborate using a tool they are already familiar with (and our IT dept will not let us install git or similar).  So I'd like to figure out how to get this to work, if possible, and why it is only a problem in GAMS.

Any insights?  In particular, anyone know what the GAMSNext file that GAMS seems to be trying to write is?  Also, why is GAMS perfectly able to save files to SharePoint when I create my project file (the .gpr file was, in fact, saved just fine), but not when I try to save a change to my .gms file?  What is the difference in the GAMS save process for a .gms file and a .gpr file?

Comment: I noted that whether I have a project open in the SharePoint drive or the local drive affects how GAMS displays the information in the "About" screen.  If I load a project from my local hard drive, then the About screen shows the proper Build, Release, Release Date, and License Date.  If I load a project from my mapped SharePoint drive, then the data for Release, Release Date, and License Date don't display, and there is a message that says: "Error.  Audit failed with rc = 113"

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue before - GAMS not running a file on a network path/drive and give a 'UNC path error' or so.

If I recall, the issue was solved when we took the project file out of the "My Documents" folder. If it is a shared drive created for windows, you may have a "My Documents" folder which has a path with "Documents". Create your GAMS folder from the root and create your .gpj and .gms files there.

Hope this helps.